# How to display post by date written (1974) and not date published (today)?

Tags: plugins, themes

Can anyone help? I'm trying to find a theme or plugin that will allow me to post several years of daily diary entries as individual WordPress posts. But I want them to appear on a continuous timeline based on the date they were originally written, not on the date that I publish them. Is that possible? Is there such a plugin or theme?

Much thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Plugin/Theme recommendations are off-topic. But you can use the default WP functionality. When you open your post editor, on the right you have a "Publish" box, with the following fields: Status, Visibility and Published on. Just edit the "Published on" field with the desired date.

Comment: @denis.stoyanov That should be an answer instead.

Comment: @kaiser Yes I know, but the question is a bit off-topic, so I've decided to post it as a comment instead :)

Comment: @denis.stoyanov That's not off topic. And that really would be a good answer (and receive an upvote).

Comment: @kaiser Hm, I see. I thought it's a bit off-topic. Anyway it doesn't matter whether it's a comment or an answer, helping is what it counts :).

Comment: Yes, but without an answer this will stay open until forever. Please: As an answer.

Comment: user80814, how do you have this diary entries organized? I think once I done something just like that. Entries organized in Excel, export to CSV, import with organized and correct post dates.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, [courtesy Denis](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/76287/denis-stoyanov): simply set the desired publication in the 'publish' box while editing. WordPress will then do the ordering for you.

If you insist on keeping both the publish day (today) and the written day (long ago) you will need an extra metabox to be able to store them both. How to do that is [answered here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35508/how-do-i-create-a-meta-box-for-dates).